# If the verb "got" means "have" (as in "I got something to do"), is it a past tense or present tense?

Tags: grammar, american-english, tenses, sentence

What will be the tag question of it, then? "Didn't I" or "Don't I"?

Comment: It's *past tense*. But sometimes it's said in the vernacular as *present perfect tense* to mean "I've got something to do." If *past tense*, tagging that question on it would be: "I got something to do, didn't I?" If *present perfect tense*, tagging that question on it would be: "I got something to do, don't I?"

Comment: @BenjaminHarman: Or in *British* English, *"I got something to do, **ain't** I?"* (maybe ***..., init**?* in our *latest* version of BrE! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Yes, but only if I were some chavvy yob, knob, or hob.

Comment: This question should probably be on ELL and not here. That said, people don't seem to know English very well. Sorry, but in this case, my answer is correct.

Comment: @user47014 There is a grammar of non-standard speech. That said, I don't think the OP knew what s/he was actually asking. People hear stuff on TV and in movies and repeat those things without really knowing what they are repeating.

Answer (score 3):

"I got something to do, don't I?"

is non-standard English for:

- **I've got** something to do, **haven't I?**
  OR
- **I have** something to do, **don't I?**

Both those mean the exact same thing: **the verb *have* has two simple present forms.**

Bear in mind:

- I **got** something at that store. Got there means **buy.**
- I got your socks at that store, didn't I? *got* is simple past there.

the verb ***get*** can mean many other things as well.

The non-standard form: **I got something to do, don't I?** would be considered **present**. The tag is "don't I" and it is present simple tense.

The past tense of the expression: have/have got something to do is: **had something to do and the tag is "did or didn't".**

- **I had something to do, didn't I?**

Bear in mind: non-standard here does not qualify the speaker. It merely is an identification tool in terms of sociolect. And it is not just AmE.

BBC ENGLISH

**Note the way in which we form short answers and question tags with have got and have:**

- Have you got a sore throat as well as a runny nose?
- No, I haven’t.
- But you’ve got a high temperature, haven’t you?
- Yes, I have.
- Does this music school have enough pianos?
- No, it doesn’t.
- But you have enough opportunities to practise, don’t you?
- No, we don’t.

[BBC ENGLISH](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv323.shtml)

The examples above apply to AmE also.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98679/discussion-on-answer-by-lambie-if-the-verb-got-means-have-as-in-i-got-some).

Answer (score 1):

> *I **have to** do the report*

The verb "have (got) to" expresses obligation, it is similar in meaning to *must*. The verb *have to* is **not an auxiliary**, it is a *MAIN* verb and as such can be used in all tenses: *I will have (got) to* [pure future], *I have (got) to* [present], ***I had (got) to*** [simple past] *I have had to* [present perfect], *I had had to* [past perfect] etc.

If the main clause is in the affirmative, the tag question will normally be in the negative, the correct auxiliary in this case is *do*

> I have (got) to do the report, ***don't*** I?

In American slang, *have* can be replaced by *got*

> I **got** to do the report, don't I?

Collins Dictionary says

> People sometimes use *[have got to](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/have-got-to-do-something)* in order to emphasize that they are certain that something is true, because of the facts or circumstances involved. In informal American English, the 'have' is sometimes omitted.
>
> - *See, you got to work very hard.*
> - *We'll do what we got to do.*

The simple past equivalent of “have got to” with its corresponding question tag, would be

> I had got to do the report, hadn't I?

From *[A Grammar of English Words](https://books.google.it/books?id=4wUwAQAAMAAJ&q=%22had%20got%20to%20do%22&dq=%22had%20got%20to%20do%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHu5nl5cvkAhVKmYsKHehJCH0Q6AEIWjAH)* (1938) By Harold E. Palmer [emphasis mine]

> I **had to** do this [I had **got** to do this, It was compulsory that I should do this] (I had not yet done it).

Comment: It is not American "slang or even informal in AmE. It is unschooled. If you omit the have, that immediately identifies your sociolect, basically. English has two forms of the verb have: Have you got any money? Yes, I have. Do you have any money? Yes, I do. The question as asked by the OP is not standard AmE at all.

Comment: I have to do the report=I have got to do the report.

Comment: I have got (I've got) to do the report, **haven't I**?

Comment: *I've **got** to eat something* means the same thing to me as *I have to eat something* means, or *I need to eat something, I must eat something.* Those all talk about desired/required **future eating** that hasn't happened yet. But for me *I've **gotten** to eat something* means something **completely different!!** It talks about **past eating** that definitely **did** happen: I had the chance or permission to eat something ***and did so.*** Dialects that've forgotten *gotten* perforce also lack this handy oppositional distinction for *got/gotten*.  :-)

Comment: These two are ok: *He got to work hard, didn't he? He's got to work hard, hasn't he?* It's only unschooled to use *got* to mean *has got*. It's perfectly fine to use *got* to mean *did get*, and indeed no other past tense is available for this. *Collins Dictionary* could be a **whole** lot clearer about this. Therefore the ungrammatical/unschooled/nonstandard/"incorrect" one is *He *got to work, hasn't/doesn't he?* because that one omitted the auxiliary.

Answer (score -5):

Take out the contractions to see which is correct.

> I got something to do, did I not?

or

> I got something to do, do I not?

The correct one is the latter.